# Icon URL on the consent screen does not match the icon on your homepage

Tags: google-apps-marketplace, google-apps-script-addon

As you all know, the new G Suite Marketplace Addon Publishing approval process is almost a headache.

Now, I'm recieving the following email message "Icon URL on the consent screen does not match the icon on your homepage". This message has a link to see what they are trying to explain and when you click it, it throws an error.

I sent a response back asking which of all the images uploaded they are asking to change but it seems there is a bot behind OAuth Verification Request process and same answer came back to me.

What they are trying to say with "Icon URL on the consent screen does not match the icon on your homepage"? Homepage refers to website where privacy policy is published? If so, do I have to upload my website banner or favicon?

Does anyone understands what they are asking for?

These are the images uploaded:

**1) OAuth consent screen** (Application logo dimensions are not specified, which is the correct dimension?)

[image]

**2) G Suite Marketplace SDK - Configuration** (Applications icons domensions are specified)

[image]

**3) G Suite Marketplace SDK - Publish** (Application banner dimension is defined)

[image]

Comment: This looks like a weird error message, I couldn't find anything related to it. I think you should contact [G Suite Support](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1047213?hl=en)

Answer (score 2):

I fixed by changing Application Logo to the same favicon fo the website where privacy policy for addon is published.

Hope this can help others!